# x86 assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

Can anyone tell me what the following code in x86 ASM does? It's only part of a larger file, but it's just this bit that's getting me down.

```
find_max:
  6 .LFB0:
  7         .cfi_startproc
  8         pushq   %rbp
  9         .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
 10         movq    %rsp, %rbp
 11         .cfi_offset 6, -16
 12         .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
 13         movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
 14         movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
 15         cltq
 16         movl    a(,%rax,4), %eax
 17         movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
 18         movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
 19         movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
```

Specifically,

- What's initially in %edi on line 13?
- Why is the code referencing -20(%rbp)?
- And what exactly does line 16 do?
- What's the wisdom behind switching behind the 32-bit registers and the 64-bit registers (for instance in the case of line 15)?

The C code I disassembled to get this goes something like the following:

```
extern int a[];

int find_max(int n)
{
    int max = a[n];
    int pos = n;
    int x;

    while (n > 0)
    {
        n--;
        x = a[n];

        if (x > max)
        {
            max = x;
            pos = n;
        }
    } 
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: If you have the C code, don't you already know what it's doing?  What exactly are you trying to ask?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What's initially in **`%edi`** on line 13?

`rdi` is the first parameter-passing register for the AMD/Linux 64-bit ABI.  `edi` is being used in this code since your function takes a 32-bit `int` parameter.

---

> Why is the code referencing **`-20(%rbp)`**?

It's saving the passed-in-parameter to the stack; presumably you are compiling with low or no optimization, so every variable is getting a real memory address.  If you turn up the optimizations, you'll probably see these operations disappear.

---

> And what exactly does line 16 do?

Line 16 is an array indexing operation:

```
movl    a(,%rax,4), %eax
```

The AT&T syntax for memory addressing is a little strange looking.  It breaks down as:

> segment-override:signed-offset(base,index,scale)

In your case, the array's address is being used as the offset field, you have no base register or segment override, the scale is `4` and the index register being used is `rax`.  That breaks down to something like along the lines of this C-like pseudocode:

```
eax = *(int *)((char *)a + (rax * 4))
```

---

> What's the wisdom behind switching behind the 32-bit registers and the 64-bit registers (for instance in the case of line 15)?

I don't see anything like that on line 15, but the reason it's done is because your function uses a lot of `int` - since `int` is a 32-bit type, the compiler is using 32-bit registers.  Where it doesn't matter or the compiler is using temporary registers, it's choosing the native 64-bit size.

Comment: The last line is more like `eax = *((int*)((char*) a + rax*4));`.  The code is taking into account the size of an int.

Comment: @cHao, yeah, that's a more obvious description.  I compressed some of the redundancy out of it in my example in an effort to make it match some semblance of the original code.  I'll update that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That cleared things up a lot. :)
    @cHao, thanks to you, too :)